# Can Django's .annotate() return objects?

Tags: python, django, annotate

I have a record set that looks like this (extraneous data omitted to protect the easily bored):

```
 id | user_id |            created            | units
----+---------+-------------------------------+-------
  1 |       1 | 2011-04-18 15:43:02.737063+00 |    20
  2 |       1 | 2011-04-18 15:43:02.737063+00 |     4
  3 |       1 | 2011-04-18 15:46:48.592999+00 |    -1
  4 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:02:10.687587+00 |    -1
  5 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:09:20.039543+00 |    -1
  6 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:11:21.948494+00 |    -1
  7 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:15:51.544394+00 |    -1
  8 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:16:44.623655+00 |    -1
```

And I'd like to get a result that looks like this:

```
 id | user_id |            created            | units
----+---------+-------------------------------+-------
  8 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:16:44.623655+00 |    14
  2 |       1 | 2011-04-18 15:43:02.737063+00 |     4
```

So I naturally look to `.annotate()`:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
(MyModel.objects.filter(user=u)
        .values("id","user","created")
        .annotate(stuff=Sum("units"))
)
```

The problem is that I want **objects**, not a single list of dictionaries.  I need the methods attached to those objects to be available.  Any ideas as to how to do this?

**Edit**:
I should have pointed out that I tried using .values() because without it I would get a bunch of annotated objects alright, but there would be 8 of them (as in the first query above), and not 2 (as in the second result above).  My guess is that it's not combining the rows because there's a timestamp in there making the rows different:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(user=u).annotate(Sum("units"))
# Returns 8 records, not 2 as expected
```

Comment: For the second part of the problem, the annotation, I'm not seeing quite how the first set of data leads to the second...
Why are ids 8 and 2 left with a sum of 14 and 4?
Annotate doesn't reduce the number of rows returned.

Perhaps if you added the SQL for what you were trying to acheieve

Comment: What is the normal sql query you have used to generate the result table (2 rows) displayed above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like there was some confusion when I initially asked the question, and as a result I was directed to not use `.values()` when that wasn't actually the problem.  The problem is that Django's `.annotate()` doesn't allow for the overwriting of column properties with calculated values, and only annotates objects with additional data.  This makes sense really, since if you want an object returned, you want to be able to assume that the object in question actually represents a row in the database, and not a mishmash of calculated values overwriting column values.

However, this didn't work for me, because the above functionality means that with columns like `created` (a timestamp) you can't get the calculated values I wanted without using `.values()`... and that doesn't give me objects.

So, I opted for the next best thing: `.raw()`:

```
query = """
    SELECT
        ep.product_id              AS product_id,
        ep.user_id                 AS user_id,
        MAX(ep.created)            AS created,
        SUM(eup.units)             AS units
    FROM
        ecom_unitpermission AS eup
    WHERE
        ep.user_id = 1
    GROUP BY
        ep.product_id,
        ep.user_id
"""

for perm in MyModel.objects.raw(query):
    print "%15s %3s %s" % (perm.product.name, perm.units, perm.product.somemethod())
```

Using `.defer()` might have done this for me, though [there appears to be a bug in Django 1.3 when combining that with `.annotate()`](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11890)

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't annotate but the call to values. The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) quite clearly show that annotate works on querysets. It is the values call that returns the dictionary of values and loses you the ability to access the models.

Edit to add: If you only want to bring back certain fields but still have models then use [defer](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) instead of values

Comment: Actually, I added .values() because without it, I couldn't get the result to aggregate into the two rows I expected.  I think it has to do with the fact that I've got a timestamp in there, so the rows are all different.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate returns a queryset, but you're also calling .values() which will always return a dictionary.